# Essere "uno scappato di casa"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Essere  "uno scappato di casa" non nel senso di qualcuno che sia  fuggito da casa, è un'espressione che sento usare molto,  ma solo a  Milano.

In genere si usa in riferimento ad una persona  che si trova ad avere un ruolo di cui non è all'altezza, come ad  esempio un professionista improvvisato.

Su Google non sono riuscito a trovare dettagli in merito a questa espressione, ma solo questo accenno su [Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/essere-uno-scappato-di-casa.3251961/?hl=it).

Sapete se questo modo di dire è usato anche in altre regioni? Qualcuno ha idea da dove possa derivare questa espressione?

Comment: Dove vengo io (veneziano/trevigiano) si dice *scampà pai campi*, con una connotazione leggermente diversa e più dispregiativa (per esempio si può dire di qualcuno che è malvestito ad un incontro elegante, o di qualcuno che sta facendo un lavoro proprio fatto male). AVVERTENZA: cercare la frase su google produce un discreto numero di bestemmie, come si addice ad un modo di dire veneto...

Comment: Ti posso confermare che l'espressione "sei uno scappato di casa" viene tranquillamente utilizzata qui in Liguria.

Comment: @abarisone - interessante, quindi forse è diffusa nel nord-ovest.

Comment: Il tag "phrase-origin" non dovrebbe essere "etymology"?

Comment: @Charo - etimologia si riferisce ad una parola, quando si tratta di frasi o proverbi si parla di origine.

Comment: @Gio: Se è così, si dovrebbe modificare la spiegazione del tag "etymology".

Comment: @Gio: See, for instance, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51881/etymology-for-the-phrase-butterflies-in-stomach.

Comment: Interessante modo di dire! A Roma non l'ho mai sentito, ma magari proverò a usarlo...

Comment: @Charo - “etimologia” Disciplina linguistica che studia la storia delle parole, risalendo fino al punto della storia o della preistoria di un vocabolo ( etimo). Treccani

Comment: @Gio: Penso sia qualcosa da discutere nel Meta. Cerco di porre la domanda.

Comment: Liguria. Talvolta usato e comunque in senso dispregiativo. Uno/a che non ha nulla da perdere. Es: non vorrai mica metterti con uno scappato di casa...

Comment: @Alchimista - direi che ha sempre un senso spregiativo.

Comment: @Gio si certo. È quello che ho scritto.

Comment: In dialetto piemontese l'espressione è usatissima.  Concordo con un'attribuzione "leggermente" negativa, ma è spesso usata in modo affettuoso. Mia nonna amava usare frequentemente quest'espressione per criticare con dolcezza com'ero vestito (e.g. non amava vedermi in jeans), ma non era mai un insulto.  Da http://riforma.net/index.php/Piemontese/Proverbi/A:  `A smija un scapà da ca` (Sembra uno che sia scappato di casa, improvvisamente, con i vestiti che aveva addosso, in disordine. Una persona abbigliata male).

Comment: In una parola: disadattato a vivere nel luogo di provenienza. Un’espressione che, se usata in senso dispregiativo, è moralmente scorretta perché presuppone che tutti coloro che non si adattano alle convenzioni del luogo dove sono nati meritano il biasimo dei benpensanti.

Answer (score 3):

L'espressione è molto usata in Liguria ed anche come correttamente ricorda @Enzo c'è anche il proverbio piemontese:

> A smija un scapà da ca

(Sembra uno che sia scappato di casa, improvvisamente, con i vestiti che aveva addosso, in disordine. Una persona abbigliata male) utilizzato quasi come rimprovero.

Girovagando in rete ho trovato anche questo interessante [post su un blog](http://scappatodicasa.blogspot.it/2012/02/scappati-di-casa.html) che rende ancora di più il significato del modo di dire:

> Ieri sera ho passeggiato per le vie del borgo innevato con altri due
> scappati di casa. In tutto, tre scappati di casa.
>
> Che poi, per me,
> scappati di casa non significa essere scappati da qualcuno, da
> qualcosa. O da una casa. Gli scappati di casa sono quelli
> involontariamente estranei alle convenzioni, che magari fanno lavori
> seri ma sembra stiano passando di lì.
> Anche se si concentrano come
> cani sulla ciotola restano sempre un po’ svagati. A volte piantano
> radici ma in fondo sono spiantati. Parlano quando gli viene chiesto e
> qualche volta lo fanno da soli, ad alta voce, in macchina. E pure
> gesticolando. arrivano ai matrimoni vestiti bene ma con la cravatta
> allentata. Si radono, se si radono, una basetta dritta e l’altra di
> sbieco. Mettono le scarpe da tennis tutto l’inverno, tanto anche gli
> anfibi prima o poi lasciano passare l’acqua. Sono quelli che la vita
> li costringe ogni mattina a uscir di casa così e magari gli sarebbero
> bastati altri cinque minuti, una moglie o uno specchio per essere
> apposto. Ma i minuti, le mogli e gli specchi forse sono convenzioni.
>
> Ieri sera ci siamo guardati in faccia. tre facce, sei occhi,
> centoventi anni. Facce un po’ tirate per le cose che non sono mai come
> dovrebbero essere, per il freddo da schiaffi, per le prime rughe
> intorno agli occhi. E poi ci siamo guardati i piedi: un paio di
> adidas, un paio di tiger e un paio di nike. E poi abbiamo guardato il
> ghiaccio e la neve che stavamo calpestando. E poi ci siamo messi a
> ridere.

Ricordo inoltre che mia nonna raccontava che per sdrammatizzare la situazione durante i bombardamenti che avvenivano durante la seconda guerra mondiale, quando si nascondevano nei rifugi si prendevano in giro su chi era il più scappato di casa del gruppo, cioè il più trasandato e vestito in modo improbabile.

Answer (score 0):

L'espressione "è uno scappato di casa" nel senso dispregiativo moderno nasce a Genova più di vent'anni fa. Veniva utilizzata per definire persone strane, folcloristiche oppure per definire anche persone malavitose. Pur essendo una vecchia espressione già utilizzata nel nord Italia, il suo utilizzo quotidiano nel gergo quotidiano, soprattutto nell'area  genovese,  nacque  e si insediò nel linguaggio comune intorno all'anno 1996. Utilizzato da subito dalle persone più giovani poi divenne di utilizzo comune.
Ovviamente ha un ampio utilizzo a seconda di come viene inserito nella frase, come è  tipico nella lingua genovese.
Può  avere una valenza ironica, goliardica oppure definire la persona in senso negativo.
La vicinanza con Milano negli ultimi anni ne ha amplificato l'utilizzo. Soprattutto mediante l'utilizzo del mondo editoriale che lo ha fatto diventare un espressione comune.
Quindi questa espressione gergale "moderna" ha origine genovese.

Comment: Benvenuto e grazie per la risposta! Hai qualche fonte per completarla? In questo sito si tendono a evitare risposte basate solo su esperienze personali e si cerca di citare libri, articoli, siti web attendibili. Inoltre, visto che citi l'uso nel mondo editoriale, potresti citare qualche esempio di uso di questa espressione in testi esistenti? Grazie!